# Set active appearance of a Dropdown Item in Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, koala

I have just started to create my own theme using SASS and Bootstrap, but I am having problems with an active appearance of an dropdown item inside a navbar. Honestly, I would like to change the hover appaerance as well.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
<NavLink href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-nowrap" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                        Admin
                        </NavLink>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-customblue1">
                            <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-item text-light" href="users">Users</NavLink>
                                        <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-item text-light" href="roles">Roles</NavLink>
                        </div>
</li>
```

I have set the background color of the dropdown (dropdown-menu) according to my new theme (bg-customblue1) and each item to have text-light.

But the question is if there is a nice way involving SASS to get the active and hover appearances to follow that theme?

Thanks!

/Henrik

Comment: Well, what do you mean by *a nice way involving SASS*? Do you want to *change* the value *directly within* the Bootstrap `variables.scss` or do you want to *overwrite* the value *externally* - then Sass absolutely not required. Nevertheless `.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active` is the selector.

Comment: what I mean by that is that if i create a theme using sass, it would be great if you could assign specific classes to the html elements so that you get the correct effect based on the created theme. Overriding a class using css in the web page directly wasnt exactly what I had in mind, but I understand that it will work. So that was my idea with the writing.

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap the active item should have a class `.active` added, as explained in the docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#active).

So you could modify the Bootstrap `variables.scss` and change both `$dropdown-link-active-color` and `$dropdown-link-active-bg` to the colors you want when active and `$dropdown-link-hover-color` & `$dropdown-link-hover-bg` for the colors on hover.

Or you could write your own SASS to achieve this:

```
.dropdown-menu {

  .dropdown-item:hover {
    color: $light;
    background-color: $customblue-1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-item.active {
    color: $light;
    background-color: $customblue-1;
    
    &:hover {
      background-color: $customblue-2;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approac and included that into my custom.scss, but the font-color (color) doesnt join in and override the default behaviour. Any idea why?